# Idiomatic Swift: Getter & Setter boiler plate coding

Tags: swift, getter-setter, boilerplate

While migrating some projects from Objective-C to Swift, I find myself replacing the `@property`/`@synthesize` syntax with a lot more boiler-plate code.

For example, for every `@property` I am implementing, I currently use this pattern:

```
var foo: Foo? {
    get {
        return _foo
    }
    set {
        _foo = newValue
    }
}

var _foo: Foo?
```

It ends up adding quickly. Compare this with the 2 lines in Objective-C. That doesn't feel right.

Should I just replace the code using `_foo` in my ported classes with `foo` and skip the abstraction of each `public var` behind an interface entirely?

Comment: Simply create variable foo. It will work. If you want to do something additional, then use set and get.

Answer (score 2):

As @Amit89 pointed out, you can simply use `_foo`.
In your example, adding `foo` does exactly nothing, as you simply recreated the `get` and `set` functionality already supplied with `_foo`.

If you want to control how `_foo` is set you can use property observers:

```
var _foo: Foo? {
    didSet { }
    willSet { }
}
```

If you want to control how `_foo` is retrieved, then it would indeed make sense to create a `private` version of `_foo`, and then accessing it via a computed property:

```
private var _foo: Foo?

var foo: Foo? {
    get { 
        // return `_foo` in some special way
    }

    // add a setter if you want to set `_foo` in some special way
}
```

Comment: you can even use foo. for what use an underscore?

Comment: The underscore, was only to stick with the properties already defined in the code in the question.

Comment: Yes, Swift getters and setters don't hold memory for the state, so you need a private var that holds the same and like @marcus said can be reused in the legacy methods I haven't converted yet. Still I feel this boiler plate java'ish is painful to even look at.

Comment: How would you approach the problem?

Comment: By adding @annotations like obj-c doest it? :-) Seriously, I don't have the right answer and after reading your helpful suggestion (observables can also be inited apparently, I didn't know that), I don't see any easy way.